# Recursive search for all folders and subfolders in system

Tags: vb.net

I wrote a Windows Forms script that searched for all non-hidden and non-readonly folders in my system. But the script itself, when run initially, runs for like 5 minutes. Subsequent opens take much less time. I was wondering if there is a logical error to it, so as to why its running so very slow.

```
Private Function FindSubFolders(ByVal dir As DirectoryInfo, ByVal node As TreeNode) As TreeNode
    Dim subnode As New TreeNode
    For Each folder As DirectoryInfo In dir.GetDirectories()
        If (folder.Attributes And FileAttributes.Hidden) <> FileAttributes.Hidden Then
            subnode = node.Nodes.Add(folder.FullName, folder.Name)
            subnode = FindSubFolders(folder, subnode)
        End If
    Next
    Return subnode
End Function

Private Sub SetFolders_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'Is it possible to load this on 1st (initial) form load???

    Try
        Dim node As TreeNode
        If TreeView1.Nodes.Count < 1 Then
            For Each drive As String In Directory.GetLogicalDrives
                Directory.GetLogicalDrives()
                Dim folders As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(drive)
                If (folders.Attributes And FileAttributes.ReadOnly) <> FileAttributes.ReadOnly Then
                    node = TreeView1.Nodes.Add(drive, drive)
                    Try
                        node = FindSubFolders(folders, node)
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
                        Continue For
                    End Try
                End If
            Next
        End If
        If Not IsNothing(My.Settings.Folders) Then
            If ListBox1.Items.Count < 1 Then
                For Each col As String In My.Settings.Folders
                    ListBox1.Items.Add(col)
                Next
            End If
        Else
            My.Settings.Folders = New StringCollection
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Logs.Add("04", ex.Message)
    End Try
    Logs.Add("01", "Loaded.")
End Sub
```

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428136/get-all-folder-directories-list-in-vb-net

Comment: Doing some kind of *benchmarking* might help determine where exactly the time is lost. The `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` class can be used for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few tips:

One thing you can do to speed things up is to make sure the TreeView-control does not have to repaint itself every time you add an item to it. 
Before adding any item, run ***Treeview1.BeginUpdate*** and after you have added all items run ***Treeview1.EndUpdate***

If possible, get the directories as an array, and use the node.addrange to add a whole range of directiryes at once.

From MSDN:

> To maintain performance while items
>   are added one at a time to the
>   TreeView, call the BeginUpdate method.
>   The BeginUpdate method prevents the
>   control from painting until the
>   EndUpdate method is called.   The
>   preferred way to add items to a tree
>   view control is to use the AddRange
>   method to add an array of tree node
>   items to a tree view. However, if you
>   want to add items one at a time, use
>   the BeginUpdate method to prevent the
>   TreeView control from painting during
>   the add operations. To allow the
>   control to resume painting, call the
>   EndUpdate method when all the tree
>   nodes have been added to the tree
>   view.

Check out this question for a (maybe) more easy way to fetch the subfolders:
[Get all folder / directories list in VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428136/get-all-folder-directories-list-in-vb-net)