# VB.NET add enumerated folders to directory

Tags: vb.net, list, directory

I need to create an application that will allow normal user to add folders into a directory that already contains folders.

How it's setup is that the folder is ordered by job number so we have several hundered folders all named with numbers.

What I need to do is read a directory and know what the last number in that directory is and add more folders based on user input.

I have looked on here and found tons of ways to list the directories in an existing folder.  Such as this one [Get all folder / directories list in VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428136/get-all-folder-directories-list-in-vb-net) but I am not as familiar with VB.NET as I need to be to modify that to keep last folder in the directory and use it to add more.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Show some code and examples.

Comment: i don't have anything on the keeping files.  Im kind of at a loss on what should be done to do this.